# SimpleHTTPServer of Python on MacOS X stops responding after 16.000 requests

Tags: python, macos, simplehttpserver

while programming my own RPC methods in Python I discovered some awkward behavior on MacOS X (10.9.1). I start Python's simple HTTP server like this:

> `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

And then I start Apache's HTTP benchmark utility:

> ```
> ab -n 20000 http://127.0.0.1:8000/
> This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
> Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
> Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/
>
> Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
> Completed 2000 requests
> Completed 4000 requests
> Completed 6000 requests
> Completed 8000 requests
> Completed 10000 requests
> Completed 12000 requests
> Completed 14000 requests
> Completed 16000 requests
> apr_socket_recv: Operation timed out (60)
> Total of 16343 requests completed
> ```

And that's it then... Even running "ab -n 1000 ..." 17 times yields the same result in the last run. Doing the same on an Ubuntu based system works.

Versions are:

> ```
> Python 2.7.5
> Darwin box 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
> ```

Does anybody have an idea why Python on MacOS X is not able to handle more than ~16.000 requests and if there is a possible workaround?

Thanks

Comment: You might be running out of file descriptors. Try running `ulimit -n 16384` before executing your python script

Comment: I changed it from 256 to 1024 to test, however symptoms are the same. My ulimit settings are now:

`core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
max user processes              (-u) 709
`

All other ulimits are "unlimited".

Comment: The same happens with Python 3.4.0 and 3.3.5. Works on Ubuntu...